# I get Get-WmiObject : Generic Failure error on an XP Machine. What needs to be done to get rid of this?

Tags: windows-xp, powershell, wmi

I am trying make an uninstall app which removes an application X on a regular basis. The starting point to access applications installed in a Windows machine is through retrieving them from a WMI Class called Win32_Product. But when I run the basic command like this, I get the below error.

I have searched technet and SO, but either their workarounds did not work for me or were too technical in detail which did not make sense to me.

Please help.

[SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113542/how-can-i-uninstall-an-application-using-powershell)

```
ps$ Get-WmiObject -class win32_product


IdentifyingNumber : {09959E11-AD5D-408E-96AF-E3346954D6B8}
Name              : Shared Add-in Extensibility Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 (KB908002)
Vendor            : Microsoft
Version           : 1.0.0
Caption           : Shared Add-in Extensibility Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 (KB908002)

Get-WmiObject : Generic failure
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-WmiObject <<<<  -class win32_product
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were a little more patient, I would have found the Microsoft Hotfix link in those aforementioned links for the exact problem I am facing.

Below is the link that provides the hotfix for anyone interested.

[Error message when you query Win32_Product class after you install applications by using Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI) 4.5 with "Per-User" option in Windows XP: "0x80041001 - Generic failure"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970553/)

Submit a request for hotfix and you are all set.